# problem handling Gridview_SelectIndexChanging event with an UpdatePanel ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, updatepanel

i will try to explain what i have, what i'm trying to do and what is my problem

what i have:
i have a modal with and update panel (i need it because the postback closes my modal) that has two text box, a button and a gridview.
in the textbox i write the name and the surname of a person and with the button i retrieve the data and put it in a gridview.
the gridview has a control to select the row that i want, with that row, i use the data from first three cells to change some hidenField values to use in another function.
in the bottom of the modal i have the add button that only changes a textbox to show that i have the correct data. that button is not enabled by default and the event must enable it

what i want:
i want to select the row that i need, enable the add button and fetch the data in my textbox.

where is my problem:
when i select my row, selectedindexchanging fires but nevers enables the add button so cant fetch my textbox for using it

code:

front code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalSocio" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabelSocio">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="text-primary"></asp:Label>
                </h5>
               
            </div>
            
            
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"  runat="server" > 
          
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row g-3">
                                
                                
            <div class="row">
   <div class="col-3">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBusquedaNombre" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Nombre"></asp:TextBox>
       </div>
                <div class="col-3">
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtBusquedaApellido" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Apellido"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnBuscarSocio" runat="server"  CssClass="btn btn-outline-success" Text="Buscar" CausesValidation="false" ToolTip="Buscar" OnClick="btnBuscarSocio_Click" ><span class="fas fa-search"></span></asp:LinkButton>
             
            </div>
                  </div>
             
                            <div class="table-responsive mt-3">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvSocios" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvSocios_SelectedIndexChanging"    >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Legajo" HeaderText="Nro. Socio" ></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="nombreSocio" HeaderText="Nombre" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Apellido" HeaderText="Apellido" />
                    
                   
                    
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link"  HeaderText="Seleccionar"  ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="<i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i>">
                    <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-outline-secondary" />
                    </asp:CommandField>
           </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                        No se encontraron registros!
                    </div>                        
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>
                            </div>
                                   </div>
                      </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
     
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
          
            <div class="modal-footer">
                    
                                    
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnCancelarSocio" runat="server" Text="Cancelar" CssClass="btn btn-secondary" OnClick="btnCancelar_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
                <asp:Button ID="BtnAgregarSocio" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"  CausesValidation="false"  Text="Seleccionar" CssClass="btn btn-success" OnClick="BtnAgregarSocio_Click"  />
                
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

codeBehind:

```
 protected void BtnAgregarSocio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TxtSocio.Text = hfidNombreSocio.Value;
    }

    
   
    protected void gvSocios_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = gvFormasPago.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];

        BtnAgregarSocio.Enabled = true;
            hfSocio.Value = row.Cells[0].Text;
        hfidNombreSocio.Value = row.Cells[0].Text + " - " + row.Cells[1].Text + " " + row.Cells[2].Text;

    }
```

i tried to not use the enabled attribute for test but when the click event fires the hfidNombreSocio value in that moment is empty and the modal never closes.

maybe i'm not using the update panel right.

the text box code:

```
 <div class="row">
                 
                   
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSocio" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Socio Cuenta Corriente" CssClass="form-label"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtSocio" runat="server" text="0"  CssClass="form-control"  ></asp:TextBox>
             
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnBuscar" runat="server" Visible="false"  CssClass="btn btn-outline-success" Text="Buscar" CausesValidation="false" ToolTip="Buscar" OnClick="btnBuscar_Click" ><span class="fas fa-search"></span></asp:LinkButton>   <%-- this button open the modal  --%>
                   </div>
```

Comment: Well, regardless of the code,  I was NEVER aware that introduction of a update panel allows a post-back to occur without blowing out the popup. As a general rule, a popup cannot survive a post-back - even when using a update panel. Do a quick test, and drop in a test plane jane asp.net button - see what happens when you click on it - quite sure the popup will colipase.

Comment: Add a ````HiddenField```` that you can store the value of the popup state (show / hide), as that value will persist between postbacks, and then when you reload on a postback check the value to determine if you need to show it.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal i dont know what is a test plane jane asp.net button, can you give me an example?

Comment: @JohnPete22 i dont know how i can do it because the modal pop ups with the event from the button btnBuscar  the code is this: ` ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "$('#modalSocio').modal('show');", true); `

Comment: in your pop up, drop in a standard asp.net button, have the code behind debug.print "Hello". Now press that button - it causes a post-back and your modal dialog will collapse. It takes 15 seconds to test this. As I stated I am NOT aware that a modal dialog can survive a post-back. This being the case, then trying to use a up-date panel will not help you. now if I am wrong, then my comments can be ignored and are without merit.

Comment: It sounds like the modal is only shown via code-behind events.  If your goal is to have the modal stay persistent while GridView data is refreshed upon button click, I think you're going to need to use an Ajax solution so you don't get a full Asp.Net postback.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal if i press the button from the modal it closes, but in the middle i lost the values that i put in my hiddenfields, so when i need to assing txtSocio.text = hfsocio.value in that moment hf.socio is "" because it does a post back when i click in btnagregarsocio

Comment: We learned that pop dialog gets one post-back. If a simple row click on the grid we pop is ok, then I can post a solution. However, if the pop needs more interaction, then I don't have a easy solution and not waste my time posting how to do this, since what I post will not help you. So, pop a grid, select a row - no problem - easy. (and pull get row values - again no problem. However, if you need more then just selecting the grid row in the pop dialog, then we have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, folks, this is one of those I wish someone corrected me!!

I am MOST HAPPY to have big buckets of egg on my face.

I have for some time preached that when you pop a dialog, you can't have post backs in that dialog. I stand MUCH corrected!!!!

So, lets build a grid, it allows a search, and then we can click on (select the row).

We have this:

```
    <div id="hoteldialog1" style="display:normal">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

        Enter City Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdSearchCity" runat="server" Text="Search"
            style="margin-left:25px" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdSearchCity_Click"/>
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="GridHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridHotels_SelectedIndexChanged"
            CssClass="table">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdHSel" runat="server" Text="Select"
                            CommandName="Select"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
       </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

So, when we run, we get/see this:

[image]

Now, in above I DID use CommmandName = "select" because I wanted the select row to work. (and I beyond hate all those extra templates). So I used this code to highlight the row.

```
    protected void GridHotels_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // user selected this row - highlight it
        int RowIX = GridHotels.SelectedIndex;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)GridHotels.Rows[RowIX];
        if ((ViewState["MySel"] != null) && ((int)ViewState["MySel"] != RowIX))
        {
            GridViewRow gLast = GridHotels.Rows[(int)ViewState["MySel"]];
            gLast.CssClass = "";
        }
        gRow.CssClass = "alert-info";
        ViewState["MySel"] = RowIX;
    }
```

Ok, so far so simple. And the search button in above is this:

```
protected void cmdSearchCity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels ", conn))
        {
            if (txtSearchCity.Text != "")
            {
                // filter grid by city
                cmdSQL.CommandText += " WHERE City = @City";
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtSearchCity.Text;
            }
            conn.Open();
            cmdSQL.CommandText += " ORDER BY HotelName";
            GridHotels.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            GridHotels.DataBind();
        }

    }
}
```

Again, really simple.

Ok, now the money shot. Now the Rosetta stone. Now the beef, now the magic, now the amazing!!!

The above as noted was placed in a "div", and has a update panel.

So, now lets drop in another grid!!!

We going to display some people, and pop the above hotel selector grid!!

So, we now have this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GPeople" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="Firstname"    />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"      />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"              />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province"      />

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdGetHotel" runat="server" Text="Hotels"
                            OnClick="cmdGetHotel_Click"
                            OnClientClick="return mypop(this);"
                            />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadPeople();
    }
        
    void LoadPeople()
    {
        GPeople.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * from People Order by FirstName");
        GPeople.DataBind();
    }
```

So we now have a grid of people. We now want to on a row click, pop up the hotel list.

So, I suggest jQuery.UI, as is much better (and cleaner then bootstrap dialog).

So we have this row click in above:

```
          <asp:Button ID="cmdGetHotel" runat="server" Text="Hotels"
              OnClick="cmdGetHotel_Click"
              OnClientClick="return mypop(this);"
          />
```

So in above, we have both a server side button, and then a client side js function that pops up the dialog (and ONLY returns true if we hit ok.

So, now all we need is the js code to pop up the dialog. That code is this:

```
   <script>
       selok = false;
       function mypop(btn) {

           if (selok)
               return true;


           var mydiv = $("#hoteldialog1")
           mydiv.dialog({
               modal: true, appendTo: "form",
               title: "Test dialog", closeText: "",
               width: "40%",
               position: { my: 'left top', at: 'right bottom', of: btn },

               buttons: {
                   Ok: (function () {
                       selok = true;
                       btn.click()
                   }),
                    Cancel: (function () {
                        mydiv.dialog("close")
                    })
                }
               
           });

           return false;
       }
   </script>
```

(set hotel grid display:none - jquery.ui will manage this).

So, now we get this:

[image]

So we are free to search, have post-backs, and of course select the row.

If the user hits ok, then the first grid button code runs. I did NOT use the selected index change event for that first grid (I could have), but I used this code:

```
   protected void cmdGetHotel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("hotel grid click");
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.Parent.Parent;
        Debug.Print("Grid row = " + gRow.RowIndex);
        Debug.Print("PK = " + GPeople.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"].ToString());
```

Also note, that while the pop grid is hidden? We can STILL get any data from that row, since the selected index of that grid does persist!!

eg:

```
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)GHotels.Rows[GHotels.SelectedIndex];
        Debug.Print("Grid row = " + gRow.RowIndex);
        Debug.Print("PK = " + GPeople.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"].ToString());
        // cells collection, or find control to grab any other value
```

So, I think you should dump the bootstrap dialog.

Put your 2nd nice grid + searching, post backs - what ever you want  into a div with a name, and use jQuery.UI to pop the grid. This will allow searching, post backs and then when the user selects the row and hits ok, then you are now free to close this dialog, and you have "index" of that pop set for you.

Comment: you are the best, you saved me, thanks

Comment: You are welcome. In the past had tested and attempted to use a jquery.UI dialog, but it would NOT survive post-backs. Quite sure put update panel around the div (that does not work). But, a div, and THEN update panel inside works!!! (surprise to me!!!0.  This opens up HUGE doors for building kind of pop dialogs with post-backs. Really a big deal and thus we can use server code for our dialogs. Note that button click trick with the true/false being returned. The dialog is asynchronous - but that "ok" flag makes that work.